# Pushing content on link/button click using css and jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to push content to the left of my screen to show a feed and also make the content being pushed responsive. However, the feed is not being shown and the content is not being responsive.

Can someone assist me with this please...

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aldayne/nchen1kk/)

Brief snippet

```
$('.feedTrigger').click(function(){
    $('.content-wrapper').toggleClass('feedOpen');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `workflow-feed` element is not within the `content-wrapper` element (which is how you're targeting it in the CSS), so you need to adjust the CSS and add a separate `toggleClass` for just the `workflow-feed` element.

**CSS:**

```
.workflow-feed.feedOpen {
  right: 0;
}
```

**JS:**

```
$('.feedTrigger').click(function(){
    $('.content-wrapper').toggleClass('feedOpen');
    $('.workflow-feed').toggleClass('feedOpen');
});
```

## [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nchen1kk/4/)

Comment: Thank you @APAD1. Do you know how to make the contents within responsive whenever the feed opens?

Comment: You would have to approach it differently. Instead of sliding the wrapper to the left 350px you would just keep it where it is and toggle the width of the wrapper from `100%` to `100% - 350px` and the feed from `0` to `350px`. You might be able to keep it as it is now and just set padding-left to 350px; on the `content-wrapper` but it would probably be better to use a different approach.

Comment: Oh okay, thank you for your answer. Will look into it.

Comment: I didn't realize you were using Bootstrap. One way you could approach this would be to wrap the main content in `col-sm-12` and then when the `feedTrigger` is clicked, change it from `col-sm-12` to `col-sm-8` and then have the aside set to `col-sm-4`, something along those lines.